# Using THREE.js, how to use a polyline to change part of a mesh's color and also slice it into 2 pieces?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am developing an app which uses a polyline to slice a mesh into 2 pieces interactively by the user. I have managed to draw the polyline on the 3D mesh but can’t figure out how to slice it.

Say there is a polyline drawn on the mesh (red) and around it, near the upper part. I want to change the color of the upper part (e.g., green) and then slice it out so that the mesh will split into 2 complete pieces for further processing etc.
[image: Here is a picture of what I mean]
Part of the code for drawing the polyline:

```
// update line
function updateLine() {
  
  line.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
  dot.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
}

// mouse move handler
function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  mouse.z = 0;
  mouse.unproject(camera);
  if (( count !== 0 ) && (DRAWLINE)) {
    updateLine();
 }
}

// add point
function addPoint(event){
  positions[count * 3 + 0] = mouse.x;
  positions[count * 3 + 1] = mouse.y;
  positions[count * 3 + 2] = mouse.z;
  count++;
  line.geometry.setDrawRange(0, count);
  if (DRAWLINE) {
    updateLine();
  }
}
```

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
        
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    
    if (!model) return;
    
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(model, true);
    
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        INTERSECTED = true;
        
        //Copy the intersection points to mouse coordinates (used in functions addPoint() and updateLine())
        //mouse.copy( intersects[0].point );
        mouse.copy( intersects[0].point );
        
        intersects.length = 0;  //Reset the intersection variable
    
      // on first click add an extra point
      
      if( count === 0 ){
          addPoint();
      }
      addPoint();
      
    } else { 
      INTERSECTED = false;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for painting different color on the upper part:

```
    // Highlight the area above the curve with different color
    function highLight() {
        var x = 0;
        var vertices = socketMesh.geometry.attributes.position.array;
        const color = new THREE.Color(0x00ff00);
        const colorAttribute = socketMesh.geometry.getAttribute('color');
        
        for (let i = 0; i < mapPts.length; i ++) {  
            for (let j = 0; j < vertices.length; j = j + 3) {
                if (vertices[j+1] > mapPts[i].y) {
                    
                    colorAttribute.setXYZ(j, color.r, color.g, color.b);
                    colorAttribute.setXYZ(j+1, color.r, color.g, color.b);
                    colorAttribute.setXYZ(j+2, color.r, color.g, color.b);
                    
                    console.log("processing...", x++);
                }
            }
        }
        colorAttribute.needsUpdate = true;
        console.log("End of Loop!");
    }
```

But it turns out that the color is painted everywhere on the model (see figure), instead of above the green line.

I revised the code as follow but the same things happen:

```
for (let i = 0; i < verticesCurve.length; i = i + 3) {
  for (let j = 0; j < verticesSocket.length; j = j + 3) {

    if  (verticesSocket[j+1] > verticesCurve[i+1]) {                
        for (let idx = 0; idx < colorAttribute.count; idx++) {
            colorAttribute.setXYZ(idx, color.r, color.g, color.b);
    }   

   console.log(“processing…”, loopTimes++);
    }
  }
}
```

So finally I figured out that the failure is due to the fact that the coordinates of the curve is not “local” to that of the mesh socket. Can anyone tell me how to transform the coordinates of the curve to the local coordinates of the mesh? Thanks!

[image: Result of running the above code]

Comment: Neat project. To transform the coords of the curve to localspace, couldn't you just subtract the mesh's position? ( the mesh's vertices' worldspace coord would be the mesh's position + the local vertex position ). There's also this method: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.worldToLocal

Comment: Thanks. But do you mean this :
(curve's world position) - (mesh's world position) ?
That is, I just use both objects' positions to perform a subtraction, that's all?

Comment: But the mesh's position is just at the origin :
Object { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, … }
isVector3: true
x: 0
y: 0
z: 0

Comment: I see. I meant more like (curve's vertex worldpos) - (mesh's worldpos). But if the mesh's position is zero that wouldn't matter.. I based that answer on what you said about the world/local space, but looking at the 'processing' loop I'm not sure that makes sense. Any socketvertex that's above the lowest curvevertex would be colored green, wouldn't it? Shouldn't you check for similar x & z positions or something? I bet you can find a algorithm online somewhere.. Also, is this sockets for prosthesis' or something?

Comment: I see, thanks for your comment. Yes, the socket is for prosthesis. Also, if I use the loop : 
for (let idx = 0; idx < colorAttribute.count; idx++) {
            colorAttribute.setXYZ(idx, color.r, color.g, color.b);
    }   
The color is a continuous shade. But if I use : 
colorAttribute.setXYZ(j, color.r, color.g, color.b);
colorAttribute.setXYZ(j+1, color.r, color.g, color.b);
colorAttribute.setXYZ(j+2, color.r, color.g, color.b);
it will appear as stripes as the above picture. Did I use setXYZ wrongly? I mean j is x, (j + 1) is y and (j + 2) is z. What did I miss here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah you're right when you say j=x, j+1=y, y+2=x. But setXYZ does that for you, just the line setXYZ(j, color.r, color.g, color.b) would be enough there. It will set color.r on offset j, color.g on offset j+1 and color.b on offset j+2 automatically. I hope that's a logical explanation..?

Comment: I've also been thinking about how to find the right vertices to cut.. My idea was to create a mesh between the loop points and then to use a raycaster to cast a ray from each vertex of the mesh to the center of the mesh( or a bit below? ) and see if it hits the mesh you created from the loop (and maybe check if it hits the top surface, assuming you'd only want to cut the top half?). illustrated here https://imgur.com/a/t5jX7vR. (pro paint skills). It might be a lead, its still hard to figure out I guess.. Also be aware that the edge where you cut may not be as smooth as the loop itself...

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I think we need a criteria with whatever methods we use, to determine e.g. whether the vertices casting the rays are higher than the line or lower than it. This is the most difficult part. If there is no way to figure out whether the vertices' y_coordinates are higher than the line, then it won't be done. Let me think about your idea...

Comment: https://editor.p5js.org/EthanHermsey/sketches/mE7Y9ch-r

Comment: Thanks for you update Ethan, I will take a look first. Thanks a lot!